# Find Label Control Inside ContentBody

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a label control on a page (test1.aspx) that has a master page.  I want to access a label control from the code behind of the test1.aspx page (not the master page) using FindControl.

I can make it work going directly using Button2 (see below) but I want to be able to do it using FindControl (see Button1 below).  I'm getting a NULLReference exception I believe because I don't know the proper syntax to target the label control inside a content control.

On a page without a Master page I would just use FindControl("MenuItemName1") but because the control is in the Content3 / ContentBody I believe I need more.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="VB" MasterPageFile="~/Shared/MasterPages/SiteLayout.Master" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="Test1.aspx.vb" Inherits="Test1" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" Runat="Server">
</asp:Content>
 <asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="StyleSheetPage" Runat="Server">
 </asp:Content>
 <asp:Content ID="Content3" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentBody" Runat="Server"> 

       <asp:Label ID="lblMenuItemName1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label><br /><br />
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" /><br /><br />
<asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Button" />
  </asp:Content>

 <asp:Content ID="Content4" ContentPlaceHolderID="JavaScriptPage" Runat="Server">
  </asp:Content>

 Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim C As Content
    C = CType(Me.FindControl("Content3"), Content)
    Dim lblMenuItemName As Label = C.FindControl("lblMenuItemName1")
    lblMenuItemName.Text = "hello"
End Sub

   Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    lblMenuItemName1.Text = "Direct"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution:

```
    Dim lblMenuItemName As Label = TryCast(Master.FindControl("ContentBody").FindControl("lblMenuItemName1"), Label)
```